# How do I fix Global Shortcuts when they stop working in KDE?

Tags: kde

I recently had Global Shortcuts stop working in KDE 4.

I asked around on forums and chat rooms for solutions. Some people mentioned kded.

I tried reinstalling.

After about a week I upgraded all my packages were back to normal.

However, I still don't know what runs and causes Global Shortcuts to work and would like this to be clarified if anyone knows.

Thanks.

Comment: Various reasons... from KDE Bubs to Distro packaging bugs, to idk. What version of KDE 4 are you using?

Comment: Eventually Gloval Shortcuts just seemed to work again.

Comment: I would still like to know what could be wrong.

Comment: Was using a 4.5 version. Some people pointed to KWin.

Comment: @forkul linking breakage probably. or bugs.

Answer (score 2):

When I had some problems with shortcuts, I've found manual fixing of files :

```
.kde4/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc (in my case, section: [khotkeys] )
.kde4/share/config/khotkeysrc
```

my way.

I hope, those paths might help you.

Comment: the file moved to .config/khotkeysrc